# BATCH - Find most recent file and concatenate it into another file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory with a list of files, I would like that my batch finds the most recently added file and then copies the content in another file in another directory. So far I did like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b c:\dir1\*.log') do type %%X >> c\dir2\all.log
```

The problem is that in this way it outputs for example

```
ex150422.log 1>>c:\dir2.log
```

but it doesn't copy the content..
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you shure it can find the file? add the directory name like you did in dir-command

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /od /a-d /b c:\dir1\*.log') do (
    type c:\dir1\%%x>>c:\dir2\all.log
)
```